# How to make sure a custom tool with the same name is used when I enter a directory?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

I have a directory for my notes. When I do things like moving some notes to a sub directory, I also need to make sure all the references are updated. So I've written a script to do the moving  and updating in one go. But sometimes I or the other people that share my script just forgot to use the script.

I think for situations like this, a good way is to just override a command like `mv` in the directory, like when we override the behavior of a method in a subclass.

Is there any way to do this with `bash`?

Comment: I believe there is, but I don't know the details. There is a tool that automatically enters a Python virtual environment upon entering a particular directory, look that up and see if that approach could be adjusted to your use

Comment: a function named `mv` that checks if the current directory is  in question most probably

Comment: Set up `incron` or similar to automatically run the script when files are moved instead. That way you don't have to configure every user's session.

Comment: Setup an alias in `.bashrc` files of the users.  If you want to make this global, you could put it in the /etc/profile.  If you want to go crazy, you could rename the regular `mv` to `mv2` and put your script in it's place.  but that is **not** the best solution as it messes up the regular system.

Comment: Or you could put your script in some directory, lets say `/opt/local/bin`.  Then modify the PATH variables to put /opt/local/bin first, before the regular `mv` directory `/bin`.

Comment: An other idea is to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to check for the path and last command `!:0` to trigger your script